# Low memory destroy operations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, memory

I have the following relational DB:

```
class Search
  has_many :items , dependent: :destroy
end
class Item
  has_many :sub_items   , dependent: :destroy
end
class SubItem
end
```

Items can range from 100 to 10,000.
SumItems is around 100 on average.

Trying to keep my memory low I used the following:

**class Search**

```
before_destroy  :destroy_items_in_batches
    def destroy_items_in_batches
    self.try(:items).try(:in_batches, { of: 300 } ).try(:destroy_all)
  end
```

**class Item**

```
before_destroy  :destroy_transactions_in_batches
  def destroy_transactions_in_batches
    self.try(:sub_items).try(:in_batches, { of: 100 } ).try(:destroy_all)
  end
```

It still wasn't enough , so I added a `select` into the query to reduce the memory loaded since I'm destroy it anyway so all I care about is the ID I need to remove from the database.

```
self.try(:items).try(:select,:id).try(:in_batches, { of: 300 } ).try(:destroy_all)
self.try(:sub_items).try(:select,:id).try(:in_batches, { of: 100 } ).try(:destroy_all)
```

Anything else I can do to remove the memory usage?
(besides the obvious solution of decreasing the batches size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you replace `destroy_all` with `delete_all`. `delete_all` will delete the objects (records) directly from the database without loading them into memory or reading them at all.

One caveat is that no ActiveRecord callbacks will be run so you need to deal with that yourself if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I'll implement my own dependent on destroy callback as suggested here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `destroy_all` actually instantiates each object into memory and then runs each item's callbacks before destroying just that one row from the database. Very inefficient.

Instead, as suggested by Marc, you should use `delete_all` in this order:

```
SubItem.where(conditions).delete_all
Item.where(conditions).delete_all
Search.where(conditions).delete_all
```

This will run a SQL statement like `DELETE FROM sub_items WHERE conditions...`. Three SQL statements instead of (potentially) hundreds or thousands. Should be a lot faster.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll have. delete_all with the relevant foreign key inputs and that's it: I recently started understanding that clinging to Rails too hard is bad and I should implement more native/semi-native SQL/HTML/JS instead of doing flips just so it will be "the Rails way"